# Is there an odd $x$ such that $2x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {\sigma(x)}$ and $\sigma(x^2) \equiv 0 \pmod {\sigma(x) - 1}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

**CONTEXT**

This question is a result of considerations stemming from this [closely related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/230174).

**INITIAL QUESTION**

My question is as is in the title:

> Is there an odd $x$ such that $$2x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {\sigma(x)}$$ and $$\sigma(x^2) \equiv 0 \pmod {\sigma(x) - 1}?$$

Here, $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried searching for solutions to the congruences using GP in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/), I obtain:

**For both congruences**

```
for(x=2, 10000000, if((Mod(2*x^2,sigma(x)) == 0) && (Mod(sigma(x^2),sigma(x)-1) == 0),print(x,factor(x))))
```

> No output returned.

```
for(x=2, 1000000, if((Mod(2*x^2,sigma(x)) == 0) && (Mod(sigma(x^2),sigma(x)-1) == 0),print(x,factor(x))))
```

> No output returned.

**For the congruence $2x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {\sigma(x)}$**

```
for(x=2, 10000000, if((Mod(2*x^2,sigma(x)) == 0),print(x,factor(x))))
```

> Several lines returned.  Will confirm if everything so far are even:

```
6[2, 1; 3, 1]
28[2, 2; 7, 1]
30[2, 1; 3, 1; 5, 1]
84[2, 2; 3, 1; 7, 1]
120[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 1]
364[2, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1]
496[2, 4; 31, 1]
672[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1]
840[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 1; 7, 1]
1080[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1]
1488[2, 4; 3, 1; 31, 1]
1782[2, 1; 3, 4; 11, 1]
2280[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 1; 19, 1]
3276[2, 2; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1]
3472[2, 4; 7, 1; 31, 1]
7440[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 1; 31, 1]
7560[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1]
8128[2, 6; 127, 1]
8736[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1]
8910[2, 1; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1]
9480[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 1; 79, 1]
10920[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1]
11880[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 11, 1]
12400[2, 4; 5, 2; 31, 1]
16368[2, 4; 3, 1; 11, 1; 31, 1]
16380[2, 2; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1]
18360[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 17, 1]
18600[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 2; 31, 1]
20832[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1; 31, 1]
24384[2, 6; 3, 1; 127, 1]
24840[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 23, 1]
24948[2, 2; 3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 1]
25296[2, 4; 3, 1; 17, 1; 31, 1]
26208[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1]
30240[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1]
30256[2, 4; 31, 1; 61, 1]
30294[2, 1; 3, 4; 11, 1; 17, 1]
32760[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1]
35640[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1]
37200[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 31, 1]
45136[2, 4; 7, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1]
55692[2, 2; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 17, 1]
55860[2, 2; 3, 1; 5, 1; 7, 2; 19, 1]
56896[2, 6; 7, 1; 127, 1]
57240[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 53, 1]
66960[2, 4; 3, 3; 5, 1; 31, 1]
76680[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 71, 1]
81480[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 1; 7, 1; 97, 1]
84360[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 1; 19, 1; 37, 1]
86800[2, 4; 5, 2; 7, 1; 31, 1]
90768[2, 4; 3, 1; 31, 1; 61, 1]
94446[2, 1; 3, 4; 11, 1; 53, 1]
115560[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 107, 1]
121920[2, 6; 3, 1; 5, 1; 127, 1]
122668[2, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 337, 1]
131040[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1]
149856[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1; 223, 1]
170688[2, 6; 3, 1; 7, 1; 127, 1]
173628[2, 2; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 53, 1]
199584[2, 5; 3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 1]
201960[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 11, 1; 17, 1]
211792[2, 4; 7, 1; 31, 1; 61, 1]
215760[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 1; 29, 1; 31, 1]
235600[2, 4; 5, 2; 19, 1; 31, 1]
249480[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1]
251968[2, 6; 31, 1; 127, 1]
268224[2, 6; 3, 1; 11, 1; 127, 1]
270816[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1]
288288[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1]
293760[2, 7; 3, 3; 5, 1; 17, 1]
332640[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1]
334800[2, 4; 3, 3; 5, 2; 31, 1]
336784[2, 4; 7, 1; 31, 1; 97, 1]
360360[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1]
393120[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1]
406224[2, 4; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1]
409200[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 11, 1; 31, 1]
414528[2, 6; 3, 1; 17, 1; 127, 1]
441936[2, 4; 3, 4; 11, 1; 31, 1]
445536[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 17, 1]
453840[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 1; 31, 1; 61, 1]
514080[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 17, 1]
520800[2, 5; 3, 1; 5, 2; 7, 1; 31, 1]
523776[2, 9; 3, 1; 11, 1; 31, 1]
556920[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 17, 1]
560832[2, 6; 3, 1; 23, 1; 127, 1]
574560[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 19, 1]
602784[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 23, 1]
605880[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 17, 1]
622440[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 19, 1]
629640[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 11, 1; 53, 1]
632400[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 17, 1; 31, 1]
677160[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 19, 1]
695520[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 23, 1]
698760[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 647, 1]
706800[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 19, 1; 31, 1]
739648[2, 6; 7, 1; 13, 1; 127, 1]
763308[2, 2; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 233, 1]
812448[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1]
819000[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 3; 7, 1; 13, 1]
819720[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 23, 1]
828816[2, 4; 3, 1; 31, 1; 557, 1]
853440[2, 6; 3, 1; 5, 1; 7, 1; 127, 1]
876960[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 29, 1]
884520[2, 3; 3, 5; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1]
899808[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 103, 1]
950040[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 29, 1]
979600[2, 4; 5, 2; 31, 1; 79, 1]
997920[2, 5; 3, 4; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1]
1033560[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 29, 1]
1078800[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 29, 1; 31, 1]
1097280[2, 6; 3, 3; 5, 1; 127, 1]
1108560[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 1; 31, 1; 149, 1]
1128400[2, 4; 5, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1]
1146048[2, 6; 3, 1; 47, 1; 127, 1]
1230120[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 17, 1; 67, 1]
1231776[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 47, 1]
1239840[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 41, 1]
1270752[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1; 31, 1; 61, 1]
1341120[2, 6; 3, 1; 5, 1; 11, 1; 127, 1]
1343160[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 41, 1]
1421280[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 47, 1]
1441440[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1]
1503376[2, 4; 7, 1; 31, 1; 433, 1]
1543056[2, 4; 3, 1; 17, 1; 31, 1; 61, 1]
1602720[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 53, 1]
1675080[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 47, 1]
1731264[2, 6; 3, 1; 71, 1; 127, 1]
1784160[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 59, 1]
1854360[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 17, 1; 101, 1]
1860768[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 71, 1]
1888920[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 53, 1]
1932840[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 59, 1]
2056320[2, 7; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 17, 1]
2102760[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 59, 1]
2147040[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 71, 1]
2178540[2, 2; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 2; 13, 1; 19, 1]
2194800[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 31, 1; 59, 1]
2209680[2, 4; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 31, 1]
2218944[2, 6; 3, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 127, 1]
2296476[2, 2; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 701, 1]
2316480[2, 6; 3, 1; 5, 1; 19, 1; 127, 1]
2340360[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 11, 1; 197, 1]
2388960[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 79, 1]
2467600[2, 4; 5, 2; 31, 1; 199, 1]
2489760[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 19, 1]
2509920[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 83, 1]
2530440[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 71, 1]
2594592[2, 5; 3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1]
2691360[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 89, 1]
2699424[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 103, 1]
2719080[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 83, 1]
2804160[2, 6; 3, 1; 5, 1; 23, 1; 127, 1]
2815560[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 79, 1]
2863080[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 11, 1; 241, 1]
2901696[2, 6; 3, 1; 7, 1; 17, 1; 127, 1]
2915640[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 89, 1]
2944032[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 337, 1]
3013920[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 23, 1]
3171960[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 89, 1]
3231360[2, 7; 3, 3; 5, 1; 11, 1; 17, 1]
3235680[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 107, 1]
3243240[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1]
3276000[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 3; 7, 1; 13, 1]
3310800[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 31, 1; 89, 1]
3328416[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 127, 1]
3392928[2, 5; 3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 1; 17, 1]
3535680[2, 6; 3, 1; 5, 1; 29, 1; 127, 1]
3666432[2, 9; 3, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 31, 1]
3800160[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 29, 1]
3813480[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 107, 1]
4021920[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 2; 19, 1]
4062240[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1]
4203360[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 139, 1]
4241160[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 17, 1]
4253200[2, 4; 5, 2; 7, 3; 31, 1]
4324320[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1]
4357080[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 2; 13, 1; 19, 1]
4553640[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 139, 1]
4590432[2, 5; 3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 1; 23, 1]
4687200[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 2; 7, 1; 31, 1]
5005728[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 191, 1]
5050080[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 167, 1]
5412960[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 179, 1]
5518912[2, 6; 7, 1; 97, 1; 127, 1]
5524200[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 2; 11, 1; 31, 1]
5542800[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 31, 1; 149, 1]
5654880[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 17, 1]
5691600[2, 4; 3, 3; 5, 2; 17, 1; 31, 1]
5864040[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 179, 1]
5929560[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 181, 1]
6106464[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 233, 1]
6158280[2, 3; 3, 1; 5, 1; 19, 1; 37, 1; 73, 1]
6158880[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 47, 1]
6187104[2, 5; 3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 1; 31, 1]
6187600[2, 4; 5, 2; 31, 1; 499, 1]
6299200[2, 6; 5, 2; 31, 1; 127, 1]
6320160[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 19, 1]
6379560[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 179, 1]
6420960[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 3; 13, 1]
6630624[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1; 23, 1]
6656832[2, 6; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 127, 1]
6658800[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 2; 31, 1; 179, 1]
6683040[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 17, 1]
6756480[2, 7; 3, 3; 5, 1; 17, 1; 23, 1]
6759060[2, 2; 3, 1; 5, 1; 7, 2; 11, 2; 19, 1]
6770400[2, 5; 3, 1; 5, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1]
6911760[2, 4; 3, 1; 5, 1; 31, 1; 929, 1]
6998208[2, 6; 3, 1; 7, 1; 41, 1; 127, 1]
7044840[2, 3; 3, 3; 5, 1; 11, 1; 593, 1]
7193280[2, 6; 3, 1; 5, 1; 59, 1; 127, 1]
7227360[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 239, 1]
7234920[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 29, 1]
7242048[2, 6; 3, 4; 11, 1; 127, 1]
7469280[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 19, 1]
7512912[2, 4; 3, 4; 11, 1; 17, 1; 31, 1]
7590240[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 251, 1]
7633080[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 233, 1]
7731360[2, 5; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 59, 1]
8134560[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 269, 1]
8150688[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 311, 1]
8182944[2, 5; 3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 1; 41, 1]
8222760[2, 3; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 251, 1]
8386560[2, 11; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1]
8419600[2, 4; 5, 2; 7, 1; 31, 1; 97, 1]
8517960[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 239, 1]
8717200[2, 4; 5, 2; 19, 1; 31, 1; 37, 1]
8802624[2, 6; 3, 1; 19, 2; 127, 1]
8910720[2, 7; 3, 2; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 17, 1]
8936928[2, 5; 3, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 13, 1; 31, 1]
9020256[2, 5; 3, 1; 7, 1; 31, 1; 433, 1]
9041760[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 13, 1; 23, 1]
9106560[2, 7; 3, 3; 5, 1; 17, 1; 31, 1]
9380448[2, 5; 3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 1; 47, 1]
9587160[2, 3; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 269, 1]
9646560[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 1; 29, 1]
9694080[2, 7; 3, 4; 5, 1; 11, 1; 17, 1]
9709200[2, 4; 3, 3; 5, 2; 29, 1; 31, 1]
9767520[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 1; 7, 1; 17, 1; 19, 1]
9828000[2, 5; 3, 3; 5, 3; 7, 1; 13, 1]

for(x=2, 10000000, if((Mod(2*x^2,sigma(x)) == 0) && (Mod(x, 2) == 1),print(x,factor(x))))
```

> No output returned.  This confirms that the output for the preceding GP code are all even.

**For the congruence $\sigma(x^2) \equiv 0 \pmod {\sigma(x) - 1}$**

```
for(x=2, 1000000, if((Mod(sigma(x^2),sigma(x)-1) == 0),print(x,factor(x))))

52686[2, 1; 3, 2; 2927, 1]
54549[3, 2; 11, 1; 19, 1; 29, 1]
318528[2, 6; 3, 2; 7, 1; 79, 1]
520768[2, 6; 79, 1; 103, 1]
696045[3, 1; 5, 1; 7, 2; 947, 1]
925677[3, 2; 163, 1; 631, 1]
```

**CONJECTURE**

If one could show the truth of the following conjecture, then the problem in the hyperlinked MO question would be solved:

> *Conjecture:* There is no odd $x > 1$ such that $2x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {\sigma(x)}$.

**FINAL QUESTION**

Would you be able to prove the *Conjecture*?

Comment: hint use & it's a fast and, I know I came up with how tomspeed it up and Karim added it in. and you might try using parallel commands. that or equate them to each other first then to 0.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: Does using & as a fast AND work on [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)?

Comment: if not you can replicated by nesting if, as and is only true if all are, so the first false you get cuts it short. && does a double pass routine.  Ask Karim.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: Confirmed that using & as a fast AND *does* work on Sage Cell Server.  Thanks a bunch!  =)

Comment: it comes down to the multipliers, because  the former modulus is congruent to 1 mod the later modulus. the Multiplier on the former is congruent to the difference between the two remainders sought.

Comment: I can rule out primes, switch to forcomposite.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention, @Peter!  Please write out your last two comments as an actual answer so that I can upvote.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not yet a proof, but some restrictions making it unlikely that $\sigma(x)\mid 2x^2$ is possible for an odd $x>1$

Assume there is such $x$. Then

- $x$ cannot be a prime power $p^k$ : $\sigma(p^k)=1+p+\cdots +p^k$ , hence $p\nmid \sigma(p^k)$. The only divisors of $2p^{2k}$ that are not divisible by $p$ are $1$ and $2$, but $\sigma(x)\ge 4$ is a divisor of $2x^2=2p^{2k}$
- Since $\sigma(n)$ cannot be divisible by $4$, at most one prime factor of $x$ has an odd exponent in the prime factorization. Hence $x$ must either be of the form $m^2$ or of the form $pm^2$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $m$ an odd integer. If the exponent is $1$, then the prime factor must be of the form $4k+1$
- If $p$ has exponent $1$ in the prime factorization of $x$, then $p+1\mid \sigma(x)\mid 2x^2$ hence every odd prime factor of $p+1$ must be a prime factor of $x$ and since $p+1$ cannot be divisible by $4$ but is at least $4$, $p+1$ actually must have an odd prime factor. In particular, the smallest prime factor cannot have exponent $1$.
- If $x$ has a prime factor smaller than $1\ 000$ , then $x>10^{12}$
- $x>10^9$ by brute force.